# 16.04 : "aptitude" at the command line

Tags: command-line, apt, aptitude

After upgrading to 16.04 I tried to use "sudo aptitude update" at the command line and got the error that the command was not found.  What do I need to do to be able to use it again?

Answer (score 8):

Hot tip:  You don't need 'apt-get' in 16.04, only 'apt'.   Example:

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

Answer (score 4):

You can always use

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to update your system, but if you like using aptitude

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

should install aptitude.

Answer (score 0):

Seems https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/aptitude is available.

Just open your terminal and type `sudo apt-get install aptitude`

Then try again.

Thank you.